Can you use Redragon M808/M908 customizable buttons on Ubuntu?
I am looking into buying a Redragon M908/M990 because of the customizable buttons, but I was unable to find any drivers for Linux from the company. Are there any solutions for using the provided buttons? I don't need macro support, just keymapping.

https://github.com/dokutan/mouse_m908 just a google search away

Thanks, I just googled "redragon driver linux" before and this never came up. Have a good day.
